# Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline against a specific commit SHA, using the REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to use the Azure DevOps REST API to trigger builds, but I need to do it for a particular SHA, not a named branch.

In the UI, I can do this...

[image]

However, this doesn't work in the REST API POST request...

```json
{
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "<SOME SHA>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It returns this error...

```json
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "Unable to resolve the reference 'refs/heads/c08b3a23d7bff074e1ef6441047d790723010418' to a specific version. Verify the reference exists in the source repository.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi.PipelineValidationException, Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi",
    "typeKey": "PipelineValidationException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```

Looks like Azure DevOps automatically added the `refs/heads/` prefix - as I didn't include it in my POST request.

Sadly, the documentation is lacking...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#repositoryresourceparameters

There's no description at all against the `refName` field.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The answer was staring me in the face - and after spending ages on it - I worked it out 5 minutes after posting this question on Stackoverflow ‍♂️

The documentation shows a `version` field as well. This seems to be the SHA. So this works...

```json
{
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "<my-branch>",
                "version": "<my-sha>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```